# GridControl (GridView) returns no rows

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

**EDIT: Fixed..** I believe the problem was fixed by going to Add New Item -> Persistent Classes 11.2 and adding a new persistent class through the wizard. Then I just copied the code from that and put it in my Form1 code. Works!

I was following this page very closely: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3265

I tried both ways of getting a gridcontrol setup to show records from a SQL Server database, neither worked. Both (when I ran the program) returned the columns but no rows. I am positive I have the correct SQL server name, database name and table name. Searching Google seems to return "how to get the program to show a message that says 'no rows found'" i.e. nothing useful. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.Xpo;
using DevExpress.Xpo.DB;
using DevExpress.Xpo.Metadata;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Generate the connection string to the AdventureWorks database on local SQL Server. 
        XpoDefault.ConnectionString = 
          MSSqlConnectionProvider.GetConnectionString("dsd-sql3", "PH");
        // Create a Session object. 

        Session session1 = new Session(XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(XpoDefault.ConnectionString, AutoCreateOption.None));
        // Create an XPClassInfo object corresponding to the Person_Contact class. 
        XPClassInfo classInfo = session1.GetClassInfo(typeof(Call));
        // Create an XPServerCollectionSource object. 
        XPServerCollectionSource xpServerCollectionSource1 = 
          new XPServerCollectionSource(session1, classInfo);
        xpServerCollectionSource1.Reload();
        // Create a grid control. 
        GridControl gridControl1 = new GridControl();
        gridControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(gridControl1);
        // Enable server mode. 
        gridControl1.ServerMode = true;
        // Bind the grid control to the data source. 
        gridControl1.DataSource = xpServerCollectionSource1;
    }
}

[Persistent("dbo.CallLog")]
public class Call : XPLiteObject 
{
    public Call(Session session) : base(session) { }
    [Key, DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("Oid")]
    public string Oid;
    //public string Title;
    [DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName;
    [DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("MiddleName")]
    public string MiddleName;
    [DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("LastName")]
    public string LastName;
    [DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName("Email")]
    public string Email;
    //public string Phone;
}
```

}

My coworker said that its possible the data is being loaded from the DB but not linked, and he wasn't sure how to fix it...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are creating the grid at run time (but don't understand why), is the grid showing on the form? Also are you using a standard grid (not a devexpress grid) to show the data?

Comment: The grid is showing on the form fine, with the columns I coded. It's a DevExpress GridControl (DX.11.2: Data -> GridControl). Just no rows show...

Comment: Interestingly, when I group by First or LastName, I see the names as groups with blank rows... http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/4831/gridcontrol.png